# How to have one Redis client wait for all the other Redis clients to respond?

Tags: redis, load-balancing, publish-subscribe, health-monitoring, horizontal-scaling

I have one Redis server, and multiple Redis clients. Each Redis client is a WebSocket+HTTP server that, amongst others, manages WebSocket connections. These WebSocket+HTTP servers are hidden behind a load balancer.

The WebSocket+HTTP servers provide a `GET /health` HTTP endpoint. I would like this endpoint to provide the total number of current WebSocket connections, across the whole cluster.

When one hits `GET /health`, then obviously, the load balancer will dispatch the request to only one WebSocket+HTTP server instance.

How can I make one WebSocket+HTTP server instance ask for all the other instances how many WebSocket connections they currently manage?

---

I thought of the following steps:

1. The instance uses [`CLIENT LIST`](https://redis.io/commands/client-list) to know how many Redis clients there currently are (say `n`);
2. The instance then publishes `WEBSOCKET_CONNECTION_COUNT_REQUEST` to Redis (with the assumption that all Redis clients are subscribed to this event);
3. The instance finally waits for `n` `WEBSOCKET_CONNECTION_COUNT_RESPONSE`s, sums up the counts, and returns it over HTTP.

What do you think about the above approach? Isn't it a bit too convoluted? I have the feeling I'm maybe a bit overengineering...

---

I initially thought that instances could `INCR`/`DECR` a count inside the Redis storage, but I'm not sure how to handle instances being killed (as the count should then be decremented accordingly). I think an ad-hoc solution would be preferable. Still open to ideas though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a sorted set, where the members are WS server ids and the score is the timestamp of their last "ping".

Have each WS "ping" periodically (e.g. every 10 seconds) by updating that sorted set with its id. You can use a Lua script to get the time from the server and set the member's score to make everything nice and atomic:

```
redis.replicate_commands()
local t = redis.call('TIME')
return redis.call('ZADD', KEYS[1], tonumber(t[0]), ARGV[1])
```

So if your sorted set is called "wsservers" and the WS's id is foo, you can call the script after loading it with `EVALSHA <script-sha1> 1 wsservers foo`.

To return the count, all you need to do is a range on the sorted set of the last period (i.e. 11 seconds) and count the results. You can also use this opportunity for trimming old dead servers. Of course, a Lua script is my preferred approach, and this does both tasks w/o having to actually send the raw WS members down the line to the calling client:

```
local t = redis.call('TIME')
local live = redis.call('ZRANGE', KEYS[1], tonumber(t[0])-11, '+inf')
redis.call('ZREMRANGEBYSCORE', KEYS[1], '-inf', tonumber(t[0])-11)
return #live
```

Comment: Interesting approach, cleaning on read. Something I don't get with your snippets: where is the number of current WebSocket connections per server?

Comment: Missed that req - you can use the same approach but instead of storing the server's id as element store something that concats the WS connection id. That way you'll have a unique member for each connection. Alternatively, use the same approach but also keep a string counter with the number of current connections in a separate key with a TTL that you can use to read the current count from after doing the ZRANGE.